# google app engine with django upload file error

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, upload

i am using django with google app engine . i am trying to upload images.

i made a form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="addImage" method="post">
        <p>Title of the Image: 
        <input type="text" name="title"  /></p>
        <p>Please select image to upload: 
        <input type="file" name="img" required="True"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
    </form>
```

mapping it to this view

```
def addImage(request):
    image = Image()
    image.title = request.POST.get("title")
    img = images.resize(request.POST.get('img'),50,50)
    image.blob = db.Blob(img)
    image.put()
    return HttpResponse('<html><head><meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="2; url=/"></head><body>One item added successfuly </body></html>')
```

its giving me this error in the debugging session

```
Exception Type: NotImageError
Exception Value:Empty image data.
```

WHY?????

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Google App Engine, but this is how I would do it on a pure Django 1.3 installation:

**forms.py:**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import fields

class UploadImageForm(forms.Form):
    image_file = fields.ImageField()
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from NAME_OF_YOUR_APP.forms import UploadImageForm

def addImage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        upload_image_form = UploadImageForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)

        if upload_image_form.is_valid():
            image_file = request.cleaned_data['image_file']
            # do something with the image...
            return ...

    else:
        upload_image_form = UploadImageForm()

    context = {'form':upload_image_form}
    return render_to_response('path/to/upload_template.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**upload_template.html:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{ form.image_file.label_tag }}</td>
            <td>{{ form.image_file }}</td>
            <td>{% if form.image_file.errors %}{% for error in form.image_file.errors %}{{ error }}{% endfor %}{% endif %}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Your template code looks good (it's missing `{% csrf_token %}`, which I'm not sure if GAE needs or not). Your view code should check to see if the request is a POST request or not.

In my example, I created a form called UploadImageForm, which accepts a single `image_file` to be uploaded. Logic works like so:

1. User visits example.com/upload_image
2. `addImage()` runs. Since this is a GET and not a POST request, it makes an empty UploadImageForm(), and renders it inside upload_template.html.
3. User is displayed the form.
4. User fills out the form and Submits an image.
5. Server receives POST request, and `addImage()` is called again.
6. We bind the uploaded file data to UploadImageForm.
7. If there are no errors (e.g. upload_image_form.is_valid() is True), we capture the image_file out of cleaned_data, and we can then do something with it.
8. If there are errors (upload_image_form.is_valid() is False), the template is re-displayed with error messages.

Answer (score 0):

really simple ,

edit this line:

```
img = images.resize(request.POST.get('img'),50,50)
```

with this one:

```
img = request.FILES['img'].read()
```

make sure that you are using django 1.2

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. it work for me... :)

```
def addImage(request):
  image = Image()
  image.title = request.POST.get("title")
  image.blob = db.Blob(str(request.FILES['img']['content']))
  image.put()
  return HttpResponse('<html><head><meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="2; url=/"></head><body>One item added successfuly </body></html>')
```